# How to call runtime functions from a contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, pallet-contracts, contracts

A [`chain_extension`](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/index.html) is one way to call into the runtime from a smart contract on the contracts pallet.

What other methods exist, and why might you use them instead of the extension pattern?

Answer (score 4):

With an [ink!](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs) smart contract, you are interacting with the runtime via the [`contracts-pallet`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts) and it's default defined API. If you want to extend the [`contracts-pallet`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts) API, the recommended [ink!](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs) way of doing so is to use the [chain extension](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/macros-attributes/chain-extension) feature - it's built into the [`contracts-pallet`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts) and [ink!](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs).

Of course you are not limited to this, imagine [`contracts-pallet`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/contracts) with [`evm-pallet`](https://docs.rs/pallet-evm/latest/pallet_evm/) and cross-contract interaction or even cross-chain contract interaction.