# How can I call my contract methods inside a pallet?

Tags: pallet, smart-contract, pallet-contracts

Can someone tell me how can you execute a smart contract method inside your custom pallet?

You can call your smart contract tx/query through the RPC API but how can you call it inside a custom pallet?

```
<pallet_contracts::Module<T>>::call().transfer();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward to call a contract from a pallet. I'm going to assume you're calling an ink! contract with the following message for the purposes of this answer.

```rust
#[ink(message)]
pub fn flip(&mut self, foo: u32) {
    todo!()
}
```

I'm also gonna assume this contract has already been deployed on-chain.

You'll need a couple of things:

- Some sort of coupling to `pallet-contracts`
- Knowledge about the contract's message selector and arguments

With that you'll able to use [`pallet_contracts::bare_call`](https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/pallet/struct.Pallet.html#method.bare_call) to call into our contract.

#### Coupling

Your custom pallet needs to have access to the interface from the Contracts pallet. It
can do this in one of two ways:

- [Tight coupling](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/pallet-design/use-tight-coupling/)
- [Loose coupling](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/pallet-design/use-loose-coupling/)

I'm not gonna get into the details here, but just know that you have to use *one* of
them. We'll use tight coupling for our example.

#### Selector and Arguments

The message selector is the identifier used to pick out which of the many functions in
your smart contract should be called. Assuming you have an ink! contract, you can find
this info in the metadata generated by `cargo-contract`.

When you do `cargo +nightly contract build` you'll get something like:

```
Your contract artifacts are ready. You can find them in:
/private/tmp/flipper/target/ink

  - flipper.contract (code + metadata)
  - flipper.wasm (the contract's code)
  - metadata.json (the contract's metadata)
```

In the `metadata.json` file you'll find a section like this:

```json
"messages": [
  {
    "args": [
      {
        "label": "foo",
        "type": {
          "displayName": [
            "u32"
          ],
          "type": 4
        }
      }
    ],
    "docs": [],
    "label": "flip",
    "mutates": true,
    "payable": false,
    "returnType": null,
    "selector": "0x633aa551"
  }
]
```

Find the message you want to call and take a note of the selector bytes. If your function
has any arguments you'll also need to take a note of what those are.

#### Crafting a `bare_call`

The `bare_call` function takes an `input_data` buffer. This buffer needs to be of the
form:

```
[ MESSAGE_SELECTOR | SCALE_ENCODED_ARG_1 | ... | SCALE_ENCODED_ARG_N ]
```

We can craft this as follows:

```rust
let mut selector: Vec<u8> = [0x63, 0x3A, 0xA5, 0x51].into();
let mut message_arg = 15663040u32.encode();

let mut data = Vec::new();
data.append(&mut selector);
data.append(&mut message_arg);
```

Now, to put it call together. In our pallet we'll need a `call` (so a function within the
`#[pallet::call]` macro) which will itself call `bare_call`:

```rust
pub fn call_contract(
    origin: OriginFor<T>,
    dest: T::AccountId, // <- This is the address of the deployed contract we're calling
) -> DispatchResult {
    let who = ensure_signed(origin)?;

    // Amount to transfer to the message. Not gonna transfer anything here, so we'll
    // leave this as `0`.
    let value: BalanceOf<T> = Default::default();

    // You'll have to play around with this depending on your contract. I don't recommend
    // hardcoding it but for demo purposes this'll do the trick
    let gas_limit = 10_000_000_000;
    let debug = false;

    // Remember, we pulled this out from the `metadata.json` file.
    //
    // Again, probably shouldn't be hardcoded but :shrug:
    let mut selector: Vec<u8> = [0x63, 0x3A, 0xA5, 0x51].into();
    let mut message_arg = 15663040u32.encode();

    let mut data = Vec::new();
    data.append(&mut selector);
    data.append(&mut message_arg);

    // This ends up calling our contract!
    pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
        who,
        dest.clone(),
        value,
        gas_limit,
        data,
        debug,
    )
    .result?;

    Ok(())
}
```

#### Further Reading

- https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/

  - I based this answer off [the following function](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/blob/6cb243499015134c489df1de1ffdce3be28a27f9/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L88).
- https://github.com/HCastano/decoded-2022-demo

  - Similar thing [here](https://github.com/HCastano/decoded-2022-demo/blob/493edc950d9e7af03c8f021919f15bfc9f7e1e94/runtime/src/chain_extension.rs#L127), but in the context of chain extensions.

Comment: Thanks so much, you are a godsent.

Comment: @hgminerva do you mind marking this as answered :D?

Comment: sorry I forgot, Done!

Comment: How about the opposite way? Can I call methods in a pallet inside a smart contract?

Comment: @marethyu yes, you can with chain extensions. See here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1951/how-to-call-runtime-functions-from-a-contract/1954#1954

Comment: Can you give an example for complex types like this: https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/erc1155/lib.rs#L492

Am i passing still encoded ints and vecs or do I have to deal with the complex types in substrate?