# how to call smart contract function in custom pallet?

Tags: pallet, smart-contract, substrate-node, pallet-contracts

Is there any way to call ink! smart contract function in substrate custom pallet?

We've found this [answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3949/2844) where `bare_call` function is based on older version of `contract_pallet`.

```
// This ends up calling our contract!
pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
    who,
    dest.clone(),
    value,
    gas_limit,
    data,
    debug,
)
.result?;
```

Now in updated version `bare_call` function is like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/b7c18f1f5c9dc5c4ffa683e230303f084efe82cb/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs#L1421C1-L1431C59),

```
pub fn bare_call(
    origin: T::AccountId,
    dest: T::AccountId,
    value: BalanceOf<T>,
    gas_limit: Weight,
    storage_deposit_limit: Option<BalanceOf<T>>,
    data: Vec<u8>,
    debug: DebugInfo,
    collect_events: CollectEvents,
    determinism: Determinism,
) -> ContractExecResult<BalanceOf<T>, EventRecordOf<T>> {}
```

This is our [github repo](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/e57c8b14e50a7a06de53b1efa929c92974e1a3e4/pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs#L82) and right now we are getting this error,

```
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air MarketplaceMVP_Substrate % cargo build --release
   Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/runtime)
   Compiling pallet-community-loan-pool v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/pallets/community-loan-pool)
warning: unused import: `frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance`
  --> pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:58:6
   |
58 |     use frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance;
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

error[E0308]: arguments to this function are incorrect
    --> pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:264:4
     |
264  |             pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
     |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
...
268  |                 gas_limit,
     |                 --------- expected struct `Weight`, found integer
     |
note: expected pallet_contracts::Config::Currency, found pallet::Config::Currency
    --> pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:267:5
     |
267  |                 value,
     |                 ^^^^^
     = note: expected associated type `<<T as pallet_contracts::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance`
                found associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance`
note: expected pallet_contracts::Config::Currency, found pallet::Config::Currency
    --> pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:269:5
     |
269  |                 storage_deposit_limit,
     |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<<<T as pallet_contracts::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
                found enum `std::option::Option<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
note: associated function defined here
    --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/98f2e34/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs:1160:9
     |
1160 |     pub fn bare_call(
     |            ^^^^^^^^^
help: call `Into::into` on this expression to convert `{integer}` into `Weight`
     |
268  |                 gas_limit.into(),
     |                          +++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
warning: `pallet-community-loan-pool` (lib) generated 1 warning
error: could not compile `pallet-community-loan-pool` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-666e594096483e01/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=--export-table -Clink-arg=--export=__heap_base -C link-arg=--import-memory  " SKIP_WASM_BUILD="" "/Users/ganesholi/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2023-01-01-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.68.0-nightly (574b64a97 2022-12-31)


  --- stderr
     Compiling pallet-community-loan-pool v4.0.0-dev (/Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/pallets/community-loan-pool)
  warning: unused import: `frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance`
    --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:58:6
     |
  58 |     use frame_support::traits::tokens::Balance;
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = note: `#[warn(unused_imports)]` on by default

  error[E0308]: arguments to this function are incorrect
      --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:264:4
       |
  264  |             pallet_contracts::Pallet::<T>::bare_call(
       |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ...
  268  |                 gas_limit,
       |                 --------- expected struct `Weight`, found integer
       |
  note: expected pallet_contracts::Config::Currency, found pallet::Config::Currency
      --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:267:5
       |
  267  |                 value,
       |                 ^^^^^
       = note: expected associated type `<<T as pallet_contracts::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance`
                  found associated type `<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance`
  note: expected pallet_contracts::Config::Currency, found pallet::Config::Currency
      --> /Users/ganesholi/xcav/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/pallets/community-loan-pool/src/lib.rs:269:5
       |
  269  |                 storage_deposit_limit,
       |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
       = note: expected enum `Option<<<T as pallet_contracts::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
                  found enum `Option<<<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as frame_support::traits::Currency<<T as SysConfig>::AccountId>>::Balance>`
  note: associated function defined here
      --> /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/98f2e34/frame/contracts/src/lib.rs:1160:9
       |
  1160 |     pub fn bare_call(
       |            ^^^^^^^^^

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
  warning: `pallet-community-loan-pool` (lib) generated 1 warning
  error: could not compile `pallet-community-loan-pool` due to previous error; 1 warning emitted
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air MarketplaceMVP_Substrate %
```

Comment: This answer https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3949/234 might be useful for you.

Comment: Try adding the `pallet_contracts::Config` to your `Config` (tight coupling).

Comment: I have added now getting different error can you please look at

Comment: `expected pallet_contracts::Config::Currency, found pallet::Config::Currency`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error messages clearly state:

> arguments to the function are incorrect

This has nothing to do with the change to the `bare_call` function; two additional arguments (which are not the cause of your problem).

However, it already provides one solution: `gas_limit.into()`, which converts the integer you give to the `Weight` struct.

The other two are solved with using a correct `BalanceOf<T>` type, e.g.:

```
type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as pallet_contracts::Config>::Currency as Currency<
    <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId,
```

I suggest you study [the post](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3748/how-can-i-call-my-contract-methods-inside-a-pallet/3949#3949) provided in the comments because it provides all the info you need. The problems you are facing right now are related to providing the correct arguments ([working example](https://github.com/justinFrevert/Runtime-Contract-Interactions/blob/6cb243499015134c489df1de1ffdce3be28a27f9/pallets/template/src/lib.rs#L88-L118)).